# How do I show multiple dropdown boxes in php

Tags: php, html

Im creating an application that asks the user to select three drop down boxes, after the user clicks the submit button it will show the date specified. In my code I have to put submit buttons after every drop box or else the code doesn't display one of the three drop downs and it puts the numbers in regular text. How do I fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="cov.php" method="POST">
    <?php
        
    ?>
    <?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
            echo"<h2>Enter birthdate</h2>";
            echo'<label for="year">Year:</label><select name="year" id="year"><option selected="selected"></option>';
            foreach (range(1921,2021,1) as $Years){  
                echo "<option value='".strtolower($Years)."'>$Years</option>";
            }
            echo'<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>';
            echo'<label for="month">Month:</label><select name="month" id="month"><option selected="selected"></option>';
            foreach (range(1,12,1) as $Month) {  
                echo "<option value='".strtolower($Month)."'>$Month</option>";
            }
            echo'<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>';
            echo'<label for="Day">Day:</label><select name="Day" id="Day"><option selected="selected"></option>';
            foreach (range(1,31,1) as $Day) {  
                echo "<option value='".strtolower($Day)."'>$Day</option>";
            }
            echo'<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>';
        }
        else{
            $Year = (int)$_REQUEST["year"];
            $currentMonth = (int)$_REQUEST["month"];
            $currentDay = (int)$_REQUEST["Day"];

            $Month = array(1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June',
            7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December');

            function getSuffix($number) {
                $number = abs($number) % 100;
                $lastChar = substr($number, -1, 1);
                switch ($lastChar) {
                    case '1' : return ($number == '11') ? 'th' : 'st';
                    case '2' : return ($number == '12') ? 'th' : 'nd';
                    case '3' : return ($number == '13') ? 'th' : 'rd'; 
                }
                return 'th';  
            }
            if(empty($Year) AND empty($currentMonth) AND empty($currentDay)){
                echo "You forgot Year<br>";
                echo "You forgot Month<br>";
                echo "You forgot Day<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif(empty($Year) AND empty($currentMonth)){
                echo "You forgot Year<br>";
                echo "You forgot Month<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif(empty($currentMonth)AND empty($currentDay)){
                echo "You forgot Month<br>";
                echo "You forgot Day<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif(empty($Year) AND empty($currentDay)){
                echo "You forgot Year<br>";
                echo "You forgot Day<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif(empty($Year)){
                echo "You forgot Year<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif(empty($currentMonth)){
                echo "You forgot Month<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif(empty($currentDay)){
                echo "You forgot Day<br>";
                echo "Please go back and fill out";
            }
            elseif($Year > 1921 AND $Year < 2021){
                if($currentMonth >= 1 AND $currentMonth <= 12){
                    if ($currentDay >=1 and $currentDay <= 31 and $currentMonth == 1 or $currentMonth == 3 or $currentMonth == 5 or $currentMonth == 7 or $currentMonth == 8 or $currentMonth == 10 or $currentMonth == 12){
                    }
                    elseif ($currentDay >=1 and $currentDay <= 28 and $currentMonth == 2){
                    }
                    elseif ($currentDay >=1 and $currentDay <= 30 and $currentMonth == 4 or $currentMonth == 6 or $currentMonth == 9 or $currentMonth == 11){
                    }
                }
            echo "The birthdate is $Year $Month[$currentMonth] $currentDay" . getSuffix($currentDay);
            }
            else{
                echo "Invalid Input. Please go back and fix it";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have open tag for <select> but no close tag </select>. Add echo "</select>" after your option for loop.

Comment: So I think you have an answer to your markup issue.  There are sandboxes for this type of thing as well you can experiment with to get your html correct.  With that said, I would suggest to you this is not a great interface to entering a date.  Most sites use a text input with a linked popup calendar.